# Using grep & sed to add new line after a specific existing line?

Tags: text-processing, sed, grep

I have been told that I can use `grep` & `sed` to find and change text in a file, but I do not understand enough to make it work for myself.

I have a configuration file (*lighttpd.conf*) that I need to add a new line into:

```
server.modules  += (
        "mod_setenv"
)
setenv.add-response-header = ( "X-UA-Compatible" => "IE=edge",
                               "X-Frame-Options" => "Deny" )
setenv.add-environment = ("LC_ALL" => "en_US.UTF-8")
$HTTP["url"] =~ "config.js$" {
        setenv.add-response-header = ( "Cache-Control" => "no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0" )
}

ssl.cipher-list = "!aNULL:kECDH+AESGCM:ECDH+AESGCM:RSA+AESGCM:kECDH+AES:ECDH+AES:RSA+AES"
ssl.dh-file = "/etc/lighttpd/dhparams.pem"

$HTTP["url"] =~ "^/restapi" {
    proxy.server = ( "" =>
                    ((
                      "host" => "127.0.0.1",
                      "port" => "9202"
                    ))
                   )
}

url.rewrite-if-not-file = ( "^/ui(?!\.\w+$)" => "/index.html",
"^/login" => "/index.html" )

server.stream-response-body = 2

#------HTTPPORT_CONFIG START------
#------HTTPPORT_CONFIG END------
```

I need to add the line `ssl.ca-file = "/etc/lighttpd/ca-cert.pem"` after the line `ssl.dh-file = "/etc/lighttpd/dhparams.pem"` like this:

```
ssl.cipher-list = "!aNULL:kECDH+AESGCM:ECDH+AESGCM:RSA+AESGCM:kECDH+AES:ECDH+AES:RSA+AES"
ssl.dh-file = "/etc/lighttpd/dhparams.pem"
ssl.ca-file = "/etc/lighttpd/ca-cert.pem"

$HTTP["url"] =~ "^/restapi" {
    proxy.server = ( "" =>
```

I have spent a few hours trying to understand RegEx but I cannot even work out the string needed to to locate the ssl.dh-file line, let alone how to insert a new line after it.

I would be very grateful if someone can help me.

Comment: Can you assume it's not already there? Or are you OK if it's added twice?

Comment: Is this a one-off or a recurring action? For a one-off - use an interactive editor.

Comment: Also, what operating system are you using? Can we assume GNU tools (default on Linux)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only tricky part I see is that your pattern and replacement strings contain forward slashes - so to avoid having to escape them, you'll want to set a different delimiter such as `%` for sed ex.

```
sed '
\%^ssl.dh-file = "/etc/lighttpd/dhparams.pem"%a\
ssl.ca-file = "/etc/lighttpd/ca-cert.pem"
' lighttpd.conf
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this is perfect. I doubt I would have ever worked that out for myself. I really appreciate your help. Pin.